# Decimal Degrees to Hours, Mins, Secs in PHP via a variable

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a php/javascript code that takes a GPS coordinate from an Iphone/website app (instamapper) and adds it to my website page.  (using snippets of other peoples code examples so far) I'd like to change the popup from displaying the decimal coordinates to proper Lat / Long but cant quite work it out.  Any help or pointers you guys could give would be great.  My code is below.

found here http://www.morvargh-sailing.co.uk/tracker/test2.php

```html
<?php

$key = "16194603621692259587";

$fichier = "http://www.instamapper.com/api?action=getPositions&key=".$key."&num=1";
$fp=@fopen($fichier,"r");
$texte = "";


if($fp)
{
while(!feof($fp))
{
$texte .= fgets($fp,1024);
}

}
$donnees = explode(',',$texte);

/*

0 : first line plus device number
1 :  Device label
2. Position timestamp in UTC (number of seconds since January 1, 1970)
3. Latitude
4. Longitude
5. Altitude in meters
6. Speed in meters / second
7. Heading in degrees 



*/
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$name = $donnees[1];
$date = date('H:i:s d-m-Y e', $donnees[2]);
$lat = $donnees[3];
$longitude = $donnees[4];
$altitude = $donnees[5];
$speed = $donnees[6];
$heading = $donnees[7];



echo('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <title>Where am I</title> 
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA_GqVjhr7wgurGjr_zR-wJxSbxjqNwl0XTkuBKGwUYonF3JCDWBRyXrxgjwLgrUjcet0gLjyGZOGwCA" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <style type="text/css"> 
            v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
            html, body {width: 100%; height: 350px}
            body, form, p {margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align:center; font-family:"lucida grande","trebuchet ms",sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
            a:link, a:visited, a:hover {color: #369; background:transparent; text-decoration: none;}
            #instamapper {position:absolute; left:80px; bottom:10px;}
            #instamapper p {text-align:right;}
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body onLoad="showAddress(\''.$lat.', '.$longitude.'\'); return false" onunload="GUnload()"> 

        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div> 

        <div id="instamapper"> 
            <p> 
                GPS tracking powered by <a href="http://www.instamapper.com/">InstaMapper</a> 
            <p> 
        <div> 

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        //<![CDATA[ 
            var momento = "'.$date.'"; 
            var altitud = "'.$altitude.'" + "m"; 
            var velocidad = "'.$speed.'" + " Km/h";
            var longitude = "'.$longitude.'";
            var latitude = "'.$lat.'";

            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 
                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map")); 
                var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder(); 

                map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl()); 
                map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); 

                function showAddress(address) { 
                    geocoder.getLatLng( 
                        address, 
                        function(point) { 
                            if (!point) { 
                                alert("\"" + address + "\" no encontrado"); 
                            } else { 
                                map.setCenter(point, 12); 
                                var marker = new GMarker(point); 
                                var info = "<b>Last known location:</b><p>Time: " + momento + "<br>Latitude: " + latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + longitude + "<br>Heading: " + '.$heading.' +"º";
                                  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(info);
                                  });                               
                                map.addOverlay(marker);
                                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(info);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }               
            }
        //]]>
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>');

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function: http://jsfiddle.net/eAUJr/1/

```
function format(newLat, newLng) {
    if (newLat < 0) {
      newLat = myround(Math.abs(newLat)) + "S";
    } else {
      newLat = myround(newLat) + "N";
    }

    if (newLng < 0) {
      newLng = myround(Math.abs(newLng)) + "W";
    } else {
      newLng = myround(newLng) + "E";
    }

    return[newLat, newLng];
  }



  function myround(val) {
    deg = parseInt(val);
    val -= deg;
    val *= 60;
    min = parseInt(val);
    val -= min;
    val *= 60;
    sec = parseInt(val);
    remainder = val - sec;
    if(remainder >= 0.5) {
      sec += 1;
    }

    return deg + "°" + min + "'" + sec + '"';

  }

document.write(format(-0.000277778, 20.292))
// output: 0°0'1"S,20°17'31"E
```